# Spring Framework: What is the specific purpose of "type" for the ProblemDetail class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

Since `Spring Framework` **6** exists available the [ProblemDetail](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.java) class.

Through some tutorials I wrote the following code:

```
//Ignore the two latest Parameters
@ExceptionHandler({CienciaNotFoundException.class})
ProblemDetail handlerMappingFor404(Exception ex, WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest req) {
    ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    problemDetail.setTitle("Resource requested does not exist");
    problemDetail.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
    problemDetail.setProperty("dateTime", DateTimeUtils.currentDateTime());
    return problemDetail;
}
```

And through `curl`, for the next command:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/777 \
     -v -H "Accept: application/json" | jq .
```

is confirmed that it returns:

```
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Resource requested does not exist",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "No existe Ciencia con 'id' 777",
  "instance": "/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/777",
  "dateTime": "2023-07-23 21:21:49"
}
```

The output works as expected, therefore:

- `instance` represents, and returns by *default*, the URI sent by the client but **without** the `http://localhost:8081/` part.
- `type` returns by *default* `about:blank`

but when `type` is customized:

- In the following tutorial: [Spring Rest - Exception Handling - Problem Details](https://dev.to/noelopez/spring-rest-exception-handling-problem-details-2hkj)  the `type` is used to return the complete `URI` request, **with** the `http://localhost:8081/` part, therefore as `http://localhost:8081/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/777`.
- In the following tutorial: [Custom WebFlux Exceptions in Spring Boot 3](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-webflux-exceptions) returns a very different `URI`

Sadly the [ProblemDetail](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.java) class is not very clear about how to use this `type` variable.

**Question**

- What is the specific purpose of `type` for the `ProblemDetail` class?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807#section-3.1

> "type" (string) - A URI reference [RFC3986] that identifies the
> problem type.  This specification encourages that, when dereferenced,
> it provide human-readable documentation for the problem type (e.g.,
> using HTML [W3C.REC-html5-20141028]).  When this member is not
> present, its value is assumed to be "about:blank".